# vectorize a bidimensional function in R

Tags: r

I have a some true and predicted labels

```
truth <- factor(c("+","+","-","+","+","-","-","-","-","-"))
pred  <- factor(c("+","+","-","-","+","+","-","-","+","-"))
```

and I would like to build the confusion matrix.
I have a function that works on unary elements

```
f <- function(x,y){ sum(y==pred[truth == x])}
```

however, when I apply it to the outer product, to build the matrix, R seems unhappy.

```
outer(levels(truth), levels(truth), f)
Error in outer(levels(x), levels(x), f) : 
  dims [product 4] do not match the length of object [1]
```

What is the recommended strategy for this in R ?

I can always go through higher order stuff, but that seems clumsy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I sometimes fail to understand where `outer` goes wrong, too. For this task I would have used the table function:

```
> table(truth,pred)   # arguably a lot less clumsy than your effort.
     pred
truth - +
    - 4 2
    + 1 3
```

In this case, you are test whether a multivalued vector is "==" to a scalar.

Comment: i will post the higher order stuff as well.

Answer (score 2):

`outer` assumes that the function passed to `FUN` can take vector arguments and work properly with them. If `m` and `n` are the lengths of the two vectors passed to outer, it will first create two vectors of length `m*n` such that every combination of inputs occurs, and pass these as the two new vectors to `FUN`. To this, outer expects, that FUN will return another vector of length `m*n`

The function described in your example doesn't really do this. In fact, it doesn't handle vectors correctly at all.

One way is to define another function that can handle vector inputs properly, or alternatively, if your program actually requires a simple matching, you could use `table()` as in @DWin 's answer

If you're redefining your function, outer is expecting a function that will be run for inputs:

```
f(c("+","+","-","-"), c("+","-","+","-"))
```

and per your example, ought to return,

```
c(3,1,2,4)
```

There is also the small matter of decoding the actual meaning of the error:
Again, if `m` and `n` are the lengths of the two vectors passed to outer, it will first create a vector of length `m*n`, and then reshapes it using (basically)

```
dim(output) = c(m,n)
```

This is the line that gives an error, because outer is trying to shape the output into a 2x2 matrix (total 2*2 = 4 items) while the function f, assuming no vectorization, has given only 1 output. Hence,

```
Error in outer(levels(x), levels(x), f) : 
  dims [product 4] do not match the length of object [1]
```